# WPF Binding error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I really don't understand what am I doing wrong here.
These are my classes:

```
class Filtro
{
    public string url;
    public string tag;
    public string tipo;

    public Filtro(string _tipo, string _tag, string _url)
    {
        url = _url;
        tag = _tag;
        tipo = _tipo;
    }

}

class MainWindow_ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Filtro> _filtros;
    public ObservableCollection<Filtro> filtros
    {
        get
        {
            return _filtros;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow_ViewModel()
    {
        _filtros = new ObservableCollection<Filtro>();
        _filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo1","tag1","url1"));
        _filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo2","tag2","url2"));
        _filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo3","tag3","url3"));
        _filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo4","tag4","url4"));
        _filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo5","tag5","url5"));
    }


}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static public MainWindow wn;
    private MainWindow_ViewModel mwvm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        wn = this;
        mwvm = new MainWindow_ViewModel();
    }
}
```

I have a `ListBox` in XAML and I'm trying to bind it to `MainWindow.wn.mwvm.filtros`. (Let's say I want to bind it to the `Filtro.url` field).

```
<Window x:Class="computrabajo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:computrabajo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow_ViewModel></local:MainWindow_ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
...
<ListBox MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding filtros}">
```

With this code I get:

> Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions
>   between types
>    'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection!1[computrabajo.Filtro]'
>   and 'System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup'. Consider using Converter
>   property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=filtros;
>   DataItem='MainWindow_ViewModel' (HashCode=38845522); target element is
>   'ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemBindingGroup' (type
>   'BindingGroup')

PS: Changed to `ItemsSource` but now I get:

> Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value
>   exists; using default instead.

Comment: `ItemsSource={Binding filtros}` not `ItemBindingGroup`

Comment: to fill listbox items use `ItemsSource` in the place of `ItemBindingGroup`

Comment: You are not setting the datacontext, do this.DataContext = new MainWindow_ViewModel();

Comment: Is your Filtro constructor doing what it should be doing? From what I can see, you're creating 5 Filtros with no data.

Comment: Yeah sorry there's a bug there. Thanks. However I shouldn't be having the "Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead"

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
<ListBox MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding filtros}">
```

Instead:

```
<ListBox MinHeight="100" ItemBindingGroup="{Binding filtros}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the `ItemsSource` instead of `ItemsBindingGroup`

```
<Window x:Class="computrabajo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:computrabajo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow_ViewModel></local:MainWindow_ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
...
<ListBox MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding filtros}">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MainWindow_ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Filtro> Filtros { get; }

public MainWindow_ViewModel()
{
    Filtros = new ObservableCollection<Filtro>();
    Filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo1", "tag1", "url1"));
    Filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo2", "tag2", "url2"));
    Filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo3", "tag3", "url3"));
    Filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo4", "tag4", "url4"));
    Filtros.Add(new Filtro("tipo5", "tag5", "url5"));
}
```

IN XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindow_ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Filtros}" />
</Grid>
```

I see this without any binding errors:

[image]

I suspect there may be an issue with assigning to the provate ObservableCollection instead of the public property in your VM. Use an auto property and see if that helps.

To view the actual data in each Filtro, either override ToString() in the Filtro class, or define a DataTemplate in the ListBox's ItemTemplate, and databind to the string properties on the Filtro class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
The first error was that I was using `ItemBindingGroup` and I should use `ItemsSource`.

The second problem is because Filtro is not a "recognizable object" (in the sense that it is more complex than a simple string or int), thus, WPF doesn't know exactly how to convert it to a string to populate the ListBox.

In that sense, I should use the `DisplayMemberPath` property in the ListBox to indicate the path to the source object. However, bindings doesn't work with Fields so I had to change `Filtro` and add the properties.

This code fixed it all:

```
<ListBox MinHeight="100" DisplayMemberPath="tag" MaxHeight="200">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Path="filtros"></Binding>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

And the Filtro class:

```
public class Filtro
{
    private string _url;
    public string url { get { return _url; } set { _url = value; } }

    private string _tag;
    public string tag { get { return _tag; } set { _tag = value; } }

    private string _tipo;
    public string tipo { get { return _tipo; } set { _tipo = value; } }

    public Filtro(string _tipo, string _tag, string _url)
    {
        url = _url;
        tag = _tag;
        tipo = _url;
    }

}
```

Thank you all for your kind answers.